# Sending ether to the winner of a game

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I was looking into the contract code for a "Deposit Ether" game on https://cryptomarketpool.com/deposit-14-eth-game-in-a-solidity-smart-contract/ and noticed this line of code:

```
    function claimReward() public {
        require(msg.sender == winner, "Not Winner");
        //this will send all the ether in this contract to the winner
        (bool sent, ) = msg.sender.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");
    }
```

I have no idea how the `(bool sent, ) = msg.sender.call{value: address(this).balance}("")` line works and am wondering if there's an explanation, especially for the first part regarding (bool sent, ).
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `call()` method return more than one values. For retrieve the first value about when `call()` executed, he uses the statement that you shared.
From documentation:

> *address.call(bytes memory) returns (bool, bytes memory)*
>
> issue
> low-level CALL with the given payload, returns success condition and
> return data, forwards all available gas, adjustable

You can see that `call` method return two values: a bool and bytes. If I want to retrieve only bool parameter, I'll write a function similar to this:

```
function isSend(address _to) public payable {
    (bool firstParameter, ) = _to.call{value: msg.value}(""); 
}
```

And this way I'll have only the first parameter that return from this `call` function.